# Highlight portion of imageView

Tags: android, imageview

Hi i guess this is quite simple solution but i cant figure it out myself.
lets say we have 4 points ( start_X, start_Y, end_X, end_Y) and we have to show the user this selection.

For now i thought best solution was to have 3 imageviews:

1. Original(nothing changed);
2. Mask(just any semi transparent color)
3. Portion(cutted out portion of original image)

and to show them as folows: 3>2>1

This solution would be great but i cant finish it. Stuck at croping an image portion and inserting it in 'the place' it belongs according to original image;

Questions are - **Is there any other solution for this problem ?** if not then - **How to crop part of image using those 4 points and then put this image very exact place it belongs ?**

**Udate 1**
Create new bitmap with transparent background (.png maybe) and same size as original image. Then add the cutted portion to it at special position and use it as image 3(described above); **Is this solution correct ? if yes how to do it ?**
[image: Desired effect]

Comment: how do you want to show rhe selection? image please...

Comment: updated with image of desired effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
class BD extends BitmapDrawable {
    private Rect mSelection;

    public BD(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        mSelection = new Rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw " + canvas.getMatrix());
        canvas.clipRect(mSelection, Op.DIFFERENCE);
        canvas.drawColor(0x66000000);
    }
}
```

test code (place it in onCreate):

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.layer0);
Drawable d = new BD(res, b);
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
setContentView(iv);
```

Comment: thats the image to draw